# InversifyJS - Inject middleware into controller

Tags: inversifyjs

I'm using inversify-express-utils using the shortcut decorators (@GET, @POST...) within a node application.

Is it possible to inject middleware into the controller to use with these decorators?

Example of what I'm trying to achieve (doesn't work):

```
export class TestController implements Controller {
    constructor(@inject(TYPES.SomeMiddleware) private someMiddleware: ISomeMiddleware) {}

    @Get('/', this.someMiddleware.someMiddlewhereMethod())
    public test() {
       ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like @OweR ReLoaDeD said, currently you can't do that with middleware injected through the controller constructor, due to the way decorators work in TypeScript.

However, you can achieve the same effect by wrapping the controller definition in a function that accepts a kernel, like so:

#### controller.ts

```
export function controllerFactory (kernel: Kernel) {

    @injectable()
    @Controller('/')
    class TestController {
        constructor() {}

        @Get('/', kernel.get<express.RequestHandler>('Middleware'))
        testGet(req: any, res: any) {
            res.send('hello');
        }
    }

    return TestController;
}
```

#### main.ts

```
let kernel = new Kernel();

let middleware: express.RequestHandler = function(req: any, res: any, next: any) {
    console.log('in middleware');
    next();
};

kernel.bind<express.RequestHandler>('Middleware').toConstantValue(middleware);

let controller = controllerFactory(kernel);
kernel.bind<interfaces.Controller>(TYPE.Controller).to(controller).whenTargetNamed('TestController');

let server = new InversifyExpressServer(kernel);
// ...
```

## UPDATE

I added an example to the [inversify-express-examples repo](https://github.com/inversify/inversify-express-example/tree/master/MiddlewareInjection) that showcases this approach using both custom and third-party middleware.

Comment: Thanks Cody, this is really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use middleware please refer to [the following unit tests as an example](https://github.com/inversify/inversify-express-utils/blob/master/test/framework.test.ts#L245-L317).

## Update

I don't think that is possible because decorators are executed when the class is declared. The constructor injection takes place when the class instance is created (which is after it has been declared). This means that, when the decorator is executed, `this.someMiddleware` is null.

I'm afraid you won't be able to inject the middleware  into the same class that uses it but you can do the following:

```
import { someMiddlewareMethod} from "middleware";

class TestController implements Controller {

    @Get('/', someMiddlewareMethod())
    public test() {
       // ...
    }

}
```

This is not a limitation of InversifyJS this is a limitation caused by the way decorators work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've edited my answer to include an example of what I'm trying to achieve.